# Design database schema in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am a rookie.I want to design database schema for web applications.Can any one give me the links for a good data base design and also start to design from scratch.

Comment: how long is a piece of string, this is to broad to be answerable

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of example database schemas that you can study here:

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

This is probably the best database designer book for a beginner:

[http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Hands/dp/0201694719](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201694719)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single "database schema" that is suitable for all web applications. You need to have a good understanding of database design principles and apply that to the web application in question. I have found [Database Systems](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Database-Systems-Implementation-Management-International/dp/0321210255) to be a good book for learning database design principles.